# Nested ng-repeat failing on inner loop

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble trying to present data from an api. The data comes in a json response organized like this [API from Guild Wars for character data](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/characters)

I made an angularJS request and used a series of nested ng-repeats to present the data, but the innermost loop , the inventory data , isn't being present properly. Only some of it is being iterated.

This is my code :

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="char in $ctrl.chars | orderBy:'-age'">
    <td>
      <table id="charTotal">     
        <ng-include src="'charBasic.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'charBags.html'"></ng-include>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Forgot to include charBasic.html :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table id="charBasic" class="charBasic">
      <tr>
        <td>{{char.name}}</td>
        <td>{{char.race}}</td>
        <td>{{char.profession}}</td>
        <td>{{char.level}}</td>
        <td>{{char.deaths}}</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="craft in char.crafting">
            <td>{{craft.discipline}}</td>
            <td>{{craft.rating}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

charBags.html :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table id="charBags" class="charBags" border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="bag in char.bags">
        <td>{{bag.id}}</td>
        <td>{{bag.size}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="inv in bag.inventory"><ng-if "{{inv}}">{{inv.id}}</ng-if></td>
      </tr>
    </table>              
  </td>
</tr>
```

As it is, not all inventory arrays are iterated, and the results vary each time

What would be the correct way to iterate this data ?

Comment: I'v never used ng-if as an element, but do you need '=' between ng-if and "{{inv}"?

Comment: I have no idea about what you're trying here: `<ng-if "{{inv}}">{{inv.id}}</ng-if>`

Comment: I've added the ng-if because I thought null values were breaking the execution, but it made no difference.Tried to add = now but it didn't change anything.The results are the same regardless of the <ng-if>

Comment: can you just output {{ bag.inventory }} to make sure it's populated?

Comment: Hi, glad to. This is one that failed iterating

Comment: [{"id":46681,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},null,{"id":73834,"count":24,"binding":"Account"},{"id":19709,"count":200},null,{"id":19709,"count":250},{"id":19713,"count":147},{"id":50025,"count":3,"binding":"Account"},{"id":19721,"count":22},{"id":36041,"count":55},{"id":77656,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},{"id":65632,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},{"id":65632,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},{"id":65632,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},{"id":45175,"count":2,"binding":"Account"},{"id":19709,"count":181},null,{"id":76989,"count":1,"binding":"Account"},null,{"id":19684,"count":216}]

Comment: Can you share the partial output of the inventory (as you said some of it is iterated)?

Comment: I uploaded the entire page :
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aUzxam6VCsN3I2WDRlM0VVUFU/view)
No idea why this is happening...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, it was a duplicate item issue :(
I "solved" it by using track-by $index option inside ng-repeat, which will bypass the problem of duplicate ids.